# Website Design not looking the same on certain computers & on mobile

Tags: html, css, image

This may seem like such a noob question, but I'm quite new with HTML and CSS.

Anyways, my problem is that on my computer, the website I'm working on looks totally fine zoomed in at 100%, normal. When I zoom out, the image on my "loading screen" moves around the screen and same when I zoom in.

Also, on other computers, the image is to the left of the text "Loading..." and some computers have it to the right of the text. Also on mobile, the background and text are way at the top of the screen while the image is in the middle of the screen on a white background.

The website page can be seen here at http://santatracking.net/loading.html

Here is my HTML code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>

    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <!--<META HTTP-EQUIV="Refresh" CONTENT="1.5;URL=homevillage.html">-->

    <script src="script.js"></script>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="loadingstyle.css">
    <link rel="preload" href="styles.css">
    <link rel="icon" type="favicon/png" href="http://santatracking.net/wp-content/uploads/2016/01/cropped-Team-yantsu-logo-transparent.png">

    <title>SantaTrackingLive</title>



  </head>

  <body>
    <div id="wrapper">
    <div class="text">Loading<span>.</span><span>.</span><span>.</span></div>

    <div id="loading">
      <img class="image" src="loadingimg.png" alt="" width="200" height="200">
    </div>
  </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Here is my CSS code

```
@font-face {
  font-family: mo;
  src: url(museo.ttf);
}

body {
  font-family: mo;
  background-image: url("bg.png");background-repeat: repeat;
  background-size: cover;
}
.text {
  position: absolute;
  width: 300px;
  height: 70px;
  font-size: 30px;
  margin: 426px 0 0 460px;
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#ffffff, rgb(183,183,183));
 -webkit-background-clip: text;
 -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
}
#loading {
    position: absolute;
    text-align: center;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    margin: -90px 0 0 -100px;
    -webkit-animation:spin 1.25s linear infinite;
    -moz-animation:spin 1.25s linear infinite;
    animation:spin 1.25s linear infinite;
    outline: 1px solid transparent; -->
}

@-moz-keyframes spin { 100% { -moz-transform: rotate(360deg); } }
@-webkit-keyframes spin { 100% { -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg); } }
@keyframes spin { 100% { -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg); transform:rotate(360deg); } }

#wrapper {
height: auto;
width: 1200px;
margin: 0 auto;
}

@keyframes blink {
    0% {
      opacity: .2;
    }
    20% {
      opacity: 1;
    }
    100% {
      opacity: .2;
    }
}

.text span {
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#ffffff, rgb(183,183,183));
   -webkit-background-clip: text;
   -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
    animation-name: blink;
    animation-duration: 1.4s;
    animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    animation-fill-mode: both;
}

.text span:nth-child(2) {
    animation-delay: .2s;
}

.text span:nth-child(3) {
    animation-delay: .4s;
}
```

If any one could help me out on this, that'd be great. Sorry again for the possible noob sounding question haha

Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

You need to use JavaScript  for that because your browser does not know the resolution  of your screen, for eg your computer is 1080 during full size but when you resize to smaller width and moves to next line. You have to use window.width to get width of your window and use DOM to manipulate HTML

Comment: do you happen to know what that would look like?

Comment: Javascript is not the only solution to this problem.

Comment: What's another solution?

Comment: If you want to avoid using JS to figure out your width at runtime, use %s instead of pixels for sizing your elements.

Comment: The browser absolutely knows the resolution of the screen (more specifically the viewport). That's what media queries are for.

Comment: Would those help the image be positioned in the same place for every viewer?